# How to fix "Certificate with thumbprint null not found in certificate store null" when trying to get plaintext from encrypted columns-sql server?

Tags: java, jdbc, ssl-certificate, always-encrypted

I have a remote `SQLserver (2017 ) version`, with a database `Test_database`, which has 1 encrypted column, encrypted using "Always Encrypted Certificate".

---

**How to decrypt the values in this column using JDBC?**

**I tried** exporting the certificate in `.pfx` format and manually adding it to the `certmgr.msc` in my system under 'PERSONAL' folder. The process works fine. But, if I try to do this programmatically, am getting the error. This is where I need, some guidance and help.

```java
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://172.24.114.121:1433;database=Test_database;user=sqlSampleLogin;password=myPass;trustServerCertificate=true;encrypt=true;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled;"
        +"keyStoreAuthentication=JavaKeyStorePassword"
        +";keyStoreLocation="+pfxCertificateLocation
        +";keyStoreSecret==myPass;";

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from Table_1");
ResultSet results = selectStatement.executeQuery();
while (results.next()) {
    String name = results.getString("name");
    String sName = results.getString("sAMAccountName"); //Error in this line, since its encrypted
    System.out.println(name +"\t"+sName+"\t");
}
```

**Expected Results:**  Decrypted values of the column "sAMAccountName"
**Actual Results:** Certificate with thumbprint null not found in certificate store null in certificate location null (SQLServerException)